# I can't resize my partition using gparted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I noticed that there are a lot of questions similar to mine on here, but I couldn't find the one that solves my issue. I have posted the image below:

[image]

I want to increase /dev/sdb12, but it won't let me use the allocated space, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Holy cow, why do you have so many tiny `ext4` partitions?

Comment: @AndroidDev I was following a guide to partition my drive and they told me to do it that way.

Comment: @dtrinh100 Can you link me to the guide you followed? That doesn't seem right....

Comment: @Pilot6 I have tried following the link that you posted, but my issue is I can't increase the size. I can decrease the size just fine though.

Comment: You can't increase size because there is no empty space at the left or right. You need to move a lot of partitions to get the unallocated space near the sdb12.

Comment: @AndroidDev It's been a year or so since I did the initial partitioning, so I don't remember where I found that guide, but it basically said to create partitions for /boot, /var, /usr, /usr/local, etc., hence is why you see all those ext4 partitions.

Comment: @Pilot6 how would I safely move the spaces? Sorry, I am very new to this partitioning thing.

Comment: It is a VERY bad idea to make many small partitions.

Comment: I suggest removing all those partitions and create one for `/` or two partitions for `/` and `/home`. The system won't work for a long time with this type of partitioning. It may be good only for servers and when you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Pilot6 would this delete all of my current files? Also, what would happen to the current /boot partition? Would it fail to boot if I deleted it?

Comment: Oh man. Yeah, you really only ever want to create a separate partition for `/home`, but even that is up to you whether you really need to do that or not.

Comment: I suggest to backup your files and doing a fresh install. it is too complicated to fix this crappy installation.

Comment: I agree with Pilot6's suggestion. You'll waste more time trying to fix this install then if you were to backup your files and do a clean install.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, I'll follow that advice. But do you know if I need to backup my Windows data as well to do a fresh install? I would be doing it from the Ubuntu Live USB.

Comment: It is always a good idea to backup. But is you don't touch Windows partitions, files should be safe.

Comment: I tend to agree that a backup of user data, fresh install, and restore may be the way to go; however, as you've got a separate `/home`, you could preserve that one to simplify the restore part. As to the original question, knowing the *exact* and *complete* error message is critical in such situations. That said, you should be able to resize `/dev/sda6`, which is highlighted; but it looks like `/dev/sda12` has little or no free space around it, so you'd need to move a bunch of partitions to resize it.